# Hi can someone help explain why my code isn't working?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Books(title, author, pages, info) {
  this.title = title
  this.author = author
  this.pages = pages
  this.info = function() {
    return this.title + 'by' + this.author + ',' + this.pages + 'pages' + ',' + 'have read!'
  }
}

var books = new Books('Behold a Pale Horse', 'Bill Cooper', 505)

books.info()
```

Comment: It works fine if you print the result of `books.info()`.

Comment: `console.log(books.info())` prints the expected message.

Comment: I also could run with no problem

Comment: For future reference, it's helpful if you describe what your code should be doing, and any error messages you're getting.

Comment: why you don't pass 4th parameter in books function,because it's required parameter in function, if you don't want to pass make it optional.

Comment: Your code is correct,if you want o see the data print/write to the standard output stream, else write to file/log.

Answer (score 2):

I was also able to run it with no problems here. I would suggest a few edits, just to make the code and printed text more readable:

```js
    function Books(title, author, pages, info) {
      this.title = title;
      this.author = author;
      this.pages = pages;
      this.info = () => {
        return this.title + ' by ' + this.author + ', ' + this.pages + ' pages' + ',' + ' have read!';
      }
    }
    
    var books = new Books('Behold a Pale Horse', 'Bill Cooper', 505);
    
    console.log(books.info());
```

Answer (score 1):

it is working, probably you meant it does not print anything?

try

```
console.log(books.info())
```

Comment: yea its not printing, just throwing an error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'books' has already been declared

Comment: then it means you set value to variable `books` twice, and your posted code is not all the code there is. try rechecking

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
console.log(books.info())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely correct.
The reason why it isn't printing the output on the console is that you haven't used `console.log(books.info())`
If you use Chrome's console you wouldn't even need to use `console.log()`